# Do phone's sync or back up their notes?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, data-transfer, google-backup

I have just got a replacement phone. I backed up all my data with google and GCloud, and then claimed on the insurance to get a new phone.

However after restoring all the data to my new phone, I have noticed the notes are missing.

I have:
ALL the tangible readable files from the old phone that can be transferred to a computer.
The system settings from the old phone, the messages, contacts, etc.
Whatever data google has synced.
The SD card from the old phone.

Unfortunately I do NOT physically have the old phone as the insurance has to take it to give me a new one.

Is there any way to get my notes back? Have they been stores anywhere I am unaware of?

The notes app is the app installed by default on my Huawei P9 Lite

Comment: This would be based on the "notes" app you were using, some do some don't. I always Google Keep so all notes are stored in the cloud. What app and does it show up in your Google account backup list?

Comment: How do I see the backup list?

Comment: @acejavelin (sorry forgot how to tag haven't used site for a while)

Comment: Go to your Google Dashboard  https://www.google.com/dashboard/b/0/ and find the section Android and open it then find your device, you will see a list of all apps that have data backed up to Google. I highly doubt your old Huawei backed up it's internal notes app there, but you can look. Note that all you can see is what apps have backed up data, you can't actually access that data without restoring it to the app.

Comment: @acejavelin it's not there, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So then unless you have the old phone and can get into the app and export or save them somewhere or somehow, the data is probably lost.

Comment: @acejavelin I called Carphone Warehouse and they still had the phone, so they were able to give it to me temporarily and I was able to screenshot them and transfer them to the SD card. So I guess this is "solved" from my point of view.